# Suddenly Visual Studio 2013 throws TF31003 connecting to VSTS

Tags: visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

Suddenly, VS2013 is throwing TF31003: "Either you have not entered the necessary credentials or your user account does not have permission to connect to the Team Foundation Server at... The following error was encountered: TF30063: You are not authorized to access to ..." in any operation trying to access to our VSTS account xxxxxxxxx.visualstudio.com.

All the team members are getting the same exception. We have VS Ultimate 2013 Update 5. We can access to that VSTS account from the browser and we can connect to it using VS2015 without problems, so it seems that the account is correct.

What we have tried:

- Reboot machine, close all VS instances and open again, etc.
- Open VS web browser and log out-log in with the admin account.
- Remove team project from VS and try to select again (Add Team Foundation Server dialog)

Comment: When does this error occur? Adding server or connecting to project? Can you clean the cache from "%localappdata%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\x.0\Cache" folder and then try again?

Comment: And can you try it again? VSTS fixed a SignIn issue yesterday: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsoservice/2016/06/21/signin-issues-with-visual-studio-team-services-621-investigating/

Comment: It occurs adding server. I cleaned the cache (both 5.0 and 6.0 versions). and tried again but error persists

Comment: Did you try the solutions here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244133.aspx?